# Angular Sending an URL parm to a webservice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Created a backend for the TOH frontend. GetHeroes() is working fine, so the basic plumbing is in place.

Having troubles passing an id into GetHero(id: number)

Postman takes the following url and returns

```
http://192.168.1.125:4200/hero-detail/23  >>>>    { "id": 23, "name": "Celeritas1" }
```

**Here is the ngOnInit from hero-detail.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('***' + this.route.params[0]);
        this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
    }
```

**Here is the GetHero() function from hero.service.ts** 
The console.log is does not seem to be getting called. 
 I am not getting an error in the web console or the ng command line window

```
private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:4300/api/heroes';  // URL to web api

 getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    console.log("enter service.getHero");
   const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Hero>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
    );
  }
```

Playing w/ the console.log in ngOnInit statement...

```
 console.log('***' + this.route.params[0]);     >>>    ***undefined

console.log('***' + this.route.params['id']);     >>>    ***undefined

console.log('***' + this.route.params );  >>>  ***[Object][Object]
```

**My question is:  It appears that the statement starting w/ switchMap is erroring out and not calling the service.  What could I try to correct the error.   And/or  how can i reference the Param array using console.log to further diagnose the issue.**

Comment: console.log('***' + this.route.snapshot.params.id); >>>>23   , but i think I am reading that snapshot is not really what you want to use.  Visit hero 21 and 23 would be cached...

Comment: how is your url constructed?  Are you using a querystring param?  What kind of routing mechanism do you have set up?  You constructing your URL with `routerLink`?  Need more info...

Comment: btw, you can set up your url params to subscribe to an observable if you think they're ever going to change...

Comment: @Blair Holmes   I posted the url and the Postman response in the question. Is that what you are asking for?     http://192.168.1.125:4200/hero-detail/23

Comment: so to use your `id`, pop it off either with the snapshot or subscribe to an observable like I said in my last comment.  Then pass that into your service and do whatever you need to with the data returned.

Comment: fwiw - the reason I asked about how your url was being constructed is because whatever name you give your parameter in your router matters to retrieving that paramter's value on the component...

Comment: @Blair Holmes. Understood, really appreciate the help. here is the relevant route { path: 'hero-detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my comment on the OP - here's an example of the snapshot route.  If the `id` is dynamic though, you should use an `observable<>`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); // coerce your id to a number since that's what your service expects
        this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(id))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here...

https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-route-parameters-in-angular-v2

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var hId: Number;
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log( + params.get('id'));
      hId = params.get('id');
    });
console.log(  hId);

        this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params.get('id')))
    }
```

Not sure which version of Angular the TOH was on when I went through it.  I guess [  ] was a valid access syntax at some point.